# Creating scrollable overflow-y when height changes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow

I want to create an `overflow-y: scroll` simply when more content is rendered on my screen after clicking a button. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.show-more', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    apiFunction.increaseSize({sizeToIncreaseTo: 2}, function(error, results, state){
          renderHits(results);
          var rightCol = $("#right-column");
          rightCol.css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="right-column">
  <div id="hits"></div>
  <div id="pagination"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="hit-template">
  {{#hits}}
  <div class="hit">
    <div class="hit-image">
      <img src="{{ image_url }}" alt="{{ _highlightResult.name.value }}">
    </div>
    <div class="hit-content">
      <h3 class="hit-name">{{{ name }}}</h3>
      <span class="stars-count">{{{stars_count}}}</span>
      <span class="stars-empty">
          <span class="stars">{{{stars_count}}}</span>
      </span>
      <span class="reviews-count">({{{reviews_count}}} Reviews)</span>
      <p class="hit-description">{{{ food_type }}} | {{{ neighborhood }}} | {{ price_range }} </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{/hits}}
</script>

<!-- Pagination template -->
<script type="text/template" id="pagination-template">
  <button class="show-more">Show More</button>
</script>
```

Above in the `apiFunction.increaseSize` function call, I increase the number of items displayed in the `#hit-template` I have shown in the HTML above. The `renderHits` function will add 2 more `.hit` divs based on the content returned by the API. When the content is shown, I simply want to make my `.right-column` a `overflow-y: scrollable` (when originally it is not scrollable). I don't want to extend the size of the `right-column`, but would rather make the entire thing scrollable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have an 'overflow: scroll', you must first make sure the height or max-height of your div should be fixed. Rest of your code is fine.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!